# jQuery creating and modifying elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an HTML snippet to insert some text into the element, then display it somewhere:

```
var elemTemp = $('<span /><strong class="value unit" />').find('span').text('hi!').end();
elemTemp.appendTo('#someDiv');
```

I want to insert "hi" inside the *span* but could not get it working. The *find()* method doesn't seem to find the span.

Comment: It looks like your selector is wrong: `$('<span /><strong class="value unit" />')`

Comment: Nideo, the selector is fine, it wraps span tags around the strong element and creates a jquery object out of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` looks down the DOM tree, but your `span` is not a descendant, so `find` won't find it. Use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead:

```
var elemTemp = $('<span /><strong class="value unit" />').siblings('span').text('hi!').end();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/LqFWG/). Note that this produces HTML along the lines of:

```
<span>hi!</span>
<strong class="value unit"></strong>
```

I'm not sure if you were aiming for that, or if you wanted the `strong` to be a child of the `span`.

Comment: Thanks, I exactly trying to do this and your solution is worked. I'm using the <span> as a label for <strong>, which looks like a disabled input area in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this as simply and quickly as possible?

```
 $('#someDiv').append('<span>hi!</span>'); // or whatever HTML you want in there
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I included the `elemTemp.appendTo('#someDiv');` line for simplicity. In actual application, this container element also creating programmatically by parsing some AJAX responses and some application logic. I want to append the elemTemp element _while_ the container element is creating.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which span-tag you want to insert "hi" into. The easiest way is to set a class on the span-tag.

HTML:

```
<span class="hello"></span>
```

jQuery:

```
$('span.hello').html('hi');
```